# More than 1 image on a subview not loading

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to add images over a ScrollView. I have the x and y point in a plist file and they are called by an enum.

```
enum {
    kLogoImage = 1,
    kNewLogoImage,
};


@implementation

- (void) _setupStaticViews
{
    UIButton *image = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [image setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [image addTarget:self action:@selector(_addContactButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    image.frame = CGRectMake(0.0 ,0.0, 150.0, 150.0);
    image.tag = kLogoImage;
    [_mapImageView addSubview:image];
    _staticViews = @[image]; 


    UIButton *image2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [image2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Time Bakground.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [image2 addTarget:self action:@selector(_addContactButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    image2.frame = CGRectMake(0.0 ,0.0, 250.0, 150.0);
    image2.tag = kNewLogoImage;
    [_mapImageView addSubview:image2];
    _staticViews = @[image2];


    for ( UIView *view in _staticViews ) {
        CGPoint point = [self _basePositionForView:view];
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = point;
        view.frame = frame;

    }
}
```

If I have only image showing, it works fine. But I need to add more than one and adding the second one causes the first one to be at xy point 0,0, and Image2 isn't visible.
How would I go about adding another image?

---

```
- (CGPoint) _basePositionForView:(UIView *)view {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", view.tag];
    NSString *stringValue = [_coordinates objectForKey:key];
    NSArray *values = [stringValue componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    if ( [values count] < 2 ) return CGPointZero;

    CGPoint result = CGPointMake([[values objectAtIndex:0] floatValue], [[values objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]);
    return result;
}
```

---

Comment: what is the code of _basePositionForView: ?

Comment: all right, last one - any chance to peek at _coordinates?

Comment: Just points to Coordinates.plist, this isn't the problem as it works just fine with my non custom buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you first make

```
_staticViews = @[image];
```

and later

```
_staticViews = @[image2];
```

Don't you rather mean to have

```
_staticViews = @[image, image2];
```

?

Comment: It happens, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate and change x accordingly in the frame:

```
for ( int iterator=0; iterator< [[_staticViews subviews] count]; iterator++){
...     
current_image.frame = CGRectMake(YOUR_IMG_WIDTH * iterator ,0.0, YOUR_IMG_WIDTH, 150.0);
...}
```

Comment: Still same problem, only now the first image has a position, and it overrides the plist file so.. Used: 
`for ( int iterator=0; iterator< [[_mapImageView subviews] count]; iterator++){
image.frame = CGRectMake(150.0 * iterator ,1000.0, 150.0, 150.0);
image2.frame = CGRectMake(150.0 * iterator ,0.0, 250.0, 250.0); 
}` –